# Ollydbg is not displaying api calls in comments. It will not analyze the program either

Tags: debugging, ollydbg

I am using Ollydbg 2.01 on Windows 7 x64. Any time I open a program, Olly does not display the API calls. Here is what I would like to see, notice the API calls in the comments section:
[image: What I want to see]

And here is what I see
[image: What I see]

Note the lack of API calls and just general info. Trying to analyze (Ctrl+A) doesn't do anything either. One thing I have noticed is that attempting to set the .UDD path file does not work. I set the API Help file (which works fine) and the .UDD path file, restart Olly, and when I look at the .UDD path, it has been replaced by a single period.

Comment: have you checked the log(Alt + L) for any messages? and what version of olly are you using? (looks like olly2, those tutorials are for olly 1.10)

Comment: I'm using olly 2.01. Earlier versions can't open any files without spawning countless error messages.  But in the messages I'm getting the error 'Different PE headers in file and in memory' in a bunch of dll files.

Comment: I solved the problem -- I wasn't using the most recent version of Olly, 2.01h I was apparently using just the 2.0. Problem is solved, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was simply not using the latest version of Olly. Downloading it solved the issue I was having.